# Cannot get auto logon to work

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am replacing a physical server running Server 2003 with a virtual server running 2008 R2. The 2003 machine auto logs on after a reboot every day (it runs control software that was not designed to run as a service)

I have duplicated the auto logon settings (and confirmed from Google searches that the same settings still apply to 2008 R2) but the machine doesn't auto logon.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I have also tried the method that uses 'control userpasswords2' and doesn't store the password in the registry,  that doesn't work either.

[image: Auto logon settings screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like everything is correct to me. It seems like a silly step since it essentially does the same thing, but you can use the sysinternals Autologon.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx

Just run the program and enter the username, domain, and password, then the enable button. As a bonus the password is encrypted, even though that probably isn't an issue for your VM.

Comment: That didn't work either.  I guess there's something deeper at work here that is preventing this server from auto logging on.  Thanks for the answer though.